# Drawing a Line in D3 (attr d) not parsing data properly

Tags: javascript, data-binding, d3.js, linechart

Using

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x( function(p) { return x( p ); })
             .y( function(p) { return y( p ); })


svg.selectAll("path")
   .data( this.data )
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("class","line " + name)
   .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d); } )
```

I would like to create a line for a plot.  I have a working implementation using `.datum` rather than `.data` (and slightly different logic).  I want to use `data` because after this call, I'm using

```
.append("text")
   .attr('x', function(d, i){return x(self.data[i][0]) })
   .attr('y', function(d, i){return y(self.data[i][1]) })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function(d, i) { return "a label"});
```

My data is formatted as an array of "tuples" (Array of length two).  It appears that the text is being appended properly, but nothing is working because I can't make the paths work.

When I log the output of `d` --- `.attr("d", function(d) { console.log(d); return line(d); })` --- I see my "tuples", however, when I log the output of x and y, each value is repeated for x *and* y.  That is,

```
     .x( function(p) { console.log("x :  "+p);return x( p ); })
     .y( function(p) { console.log("y :  "+p);return y( p ); })
```

shows

```
x :  [TIMESTAMP1]
y :  [TIMESTAMP1]
x :  [VALUE1]
y :  [VALUE1]
x :  [TIMESTAMP2]
y :  [TIMESTAMP2]
x :  [VALUE2]
y :  [VALUE2]
```

wat

I have been trying to figure out how to make the x values correspond to x values and y values correspond to y values

I have been fiddling with the line function to try to make the values come out the way I want.  The most frustrating part of it is that [the `line` documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-_line) states:

*The default accessor assumes that each input element is a two-element array of numbers:*

which is what I'm giving it.  I've tried giving it the accessor, but obviously, the data that is being fed to the `.x()` function is incorrect.

I'm trying to figure out which method is responsible for munging the data.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're doing here. Could you provide a complete example? It sound like you want to return `x(p[0])` for `.x` and `y(p[1])` for `.y` though.

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to do.  I've tried that though, and it doesn't work because the values of p are those that I posted (console output)

Comment: So what does your data look like? Did you verify that it's loaded correctly?

Comment: The data that I'm passing into `data` is an array of "tuples".  When I use `.x` and `.y`, I get the data twice. when I pass `data` directly into the line function, I get the "tuples", but it doesn't assign the `x` or `y` values correctly

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get what you mean. Are those values you've posted (e.g. `[TIMESTAMP1]`) the actual output you're getting? How are you converting those to numbers for your scales?

Comment: No, the actual output is a timestamp, but I didn't have the console output at the time.  The [VALUE] bit is an integer.  I numbered them because the integer is the same for two outputs at a time.  So the data that I'm giving the line function is something like [[2013-06-02, 213], [2013-06-01, 321], ...].  The timestamps are then parsed by d3.  The output that I get is 



x:2013-06-02
y:2013-06-02
x:213
y:213

Comment: What are your `x` and `y` functions?

Comment: The x and y functions grab the extents of the dataset.  If I'm understanding it correctly, the `x` abd `y` functions are curried, and give back a function that sets an x or y value to the proper svg coordinate value.  we're building out a wrapper for making charts, so it isn't easy to copy in the functions and have them be meaningful (multiple abstractions)

Comment: I really can't tell you what's going on without the complete code here. One thing though. You mention that it works with `.datum()` instead of `.data()`. Have you tried calling `.data([this.data])`?